# Single user id and password to connect multiple application

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-cookies

**[Scenario]**
I already have 5 PHP5.3+ applications (eg: App-A, App-B, App-C, App-D and App-E) up and running. Here, each application has its own login user-id and password.

**[New Requirement]**
Now, I want to implement the single user-id and password to login to all these applications (by using App-A). Lets say: I want to login to App-A as usual and once login I should be able to click through to other application (B,C,D and E) by simply clicking on the icon on App-A (once login).
And, my user should not be apple to login through App-B or C or D or E. They always need to connect via App-A.

**[Background]**
-All of these application are running on different domain but on the same server.
-Admin will be able to enable/disable certain App for certain user

Does anyone has done similar or anyone has any suggestion please suggest.

Comment: Read about OAuth. It'll allow you to create auth server and then use it with other apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the very good question and have done small research on your question on different ways:

## OAuth:

After reading the documentation and gone through many service providers it is not possible. Oauth service provider gives the consumer key and secret and they check the request coming from the domain and thus if the same oAuth consumer key is used on different domain Names that doesn't work.

## Setting Cookie Multiple domains

Simply, it is not possible to set the cookie without visiting the domain by any means

**Thus, I can say that it is not possible to set cookie or use the same consumer key and secret for multiple domains**

## Alternative ways

1. Use HTML5 Web Storage for storing the information and then accessing
   the information from different domains is possible.
2. Use AJAX/CURL for sending the request for setting the cookie for different domains such as example.com/session_cookie.php?info=xxxxx
3. Maintain a single sub-domain/page for all the domain for login purpose for across all the domains.

Comment: You're wrong about OAuth. It's main idea of OAuth to provide way to auth users on different domains.

Comment: I agree but he wants to use single login system on different websites and that is not possible in OAUTH

Comment: And that's how it works. After logging in on App-A you can auth user on App-B with "one click". And I think it can be also done via transparent way for user (checking session in App-A when loading App-B).

Comment: It's something different. I was talking about performing normal OAuth authentication but without triggering it by user. In point 2 you're suggesting sending session cookie to all connected apps (or maybe I misunderstand?).

Comment: Thank you guyz for you discussion. But which one of these option to follow coz I'm implementing this next week.